# Upgraded MongoDB to latest version, mongosh does not use latest version of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, installation, homebrew, upgrade, mongo-shell

I have run brew upgrade mongodb-community to upgrade mongodb to version 6.0.5.

When I run mongod -version, I get db version v6.0.5

However, when I run the mongo shell mongosh, it states that it is still using my previous version of mongodb version 5.0.7

Using MongoDB: 5.0.7
Using Mongosh: 1.8.0

Why is mongosh not using the latest version of MongoDB?

I have tried following the steps in the documentation. However, it does not seem to work.